# Python on Ubuntu: 'module' object has no attribute 'c_bool'

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.10 64Bit gives me the following trouble:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.c_bool()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'c_bool'
>>>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I do not have the same problem with Python 2.7.3 and 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04. (In case that is at all helpful for debugging.)

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a file called "ctypes.py" in the directory where you are working?  If so, move it or (preferably) rename it.

Comment: No, there is no such file in there or anywhere else on the system